# Redux-axios middleware in React Native is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

### React native app

Store(states and backend) is built with axios and redux through redux-axios middleware which requires suffixes _SUCCESS and _FAIL for the Request.
Trying to make API call with redux axios middleware. However, data is not passing to the component. Reducer is executing only Default case for some reason.

---

action:

```
import { Actions } from "../../../constants/actions";
export const getNewsBloomberg = () => {
  return {
    type: Actions.GET_NEWS_BLOOMBERG,
    payload: {
      client: "newsClient",
      request: {
        url: "top-headlines?sources=bloomberg",
      },
    },
  };
};
```

---

Reducer:

```
import { Actions } from "../../../constants/actions";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  latestUpdate: null,
  loading: null,
  error: false,
};

export const bloomberg = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.GET_NEWS_BLOOMBERG:
      return { ...state, latestUpdate: null, loading: true, error: false };
    case Actions.GET_NEWS_BLOOMBERG_SUCCESS:
      const data_string = JSON.stringify(action.payload.data);
      const data_parsed = JSON.parse(data_string);
      const data = data_parsed.articles;

      return {
        ...state,
        latestUpdate: new Date(),
        loading: false,
        data: list,
      };
    case Actions.GET_NEWS_BLOOMBERG_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        latestUpdate: null,
        loading: false,
        error: "No results found.",
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

---

index.js in Store:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { multiClientMiddleware } from "redux-axios-middleware";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import reducers from "./reducers";
//import { API_KEY } from "react-native-dotenv";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["favorites"],
};


const clients = {
  stockClient: {
    client: axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://sandbox.iexapis.com",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        token: "Tpk_27c",
      },
    }),
  },
  newsClient: {
    client: axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://newsapi.org/v2",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        apiKey: "c7c",
      },
    }),
  },
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  // applyMiddleware(client),
  applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(clients))
);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistor };
```

Reducers are combined and Provider is wrapped to the application in App.js

---

The component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, RefreshControl } from "react-native";
import { Content, Text, View } from "native-base";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getNewsBloomberg } from "../../store/actions/news";

class NewsBloomberg extends Component {
  onRefresh = () => this.props.getNewsBloomberg; //merge it

  refreshControl = (loading) => (
    <RefreshControl
      onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
      refreshing={loading}
    />
  );

  render() {
    const { data, latestUpdate, loading } = this.props.bloomberg;

    return (
      <View refreshControl={this.refreshControl(loading)} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {console.log(loading)}
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(key) => key.source.id}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <NewsItem onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")} data={data} />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state.bloomberg);
  return { bloomberg: state.bloomberg };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getNewsBloomberg,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewsBloomberg);
```

**I noticed that reducer throws the DEFAULT case only **
Does it mean that action is not dispatching or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the action creator `getNewsBloomberg` inside `onRefresh`.

```js
onRefresh = () => this.props.getNewsBloomberg();
```

Comment: I forgot to fetch it in componentDidmount first. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your mapDispatchToProps is wrong, what mapDispatchToProps does is it gives you dispatch as a first argument by using the higher order component "connect" and by using that you can dispatch your actions in react components,

now what you are doing is you are simply calling actions and not dispatching it,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  getNewsBloomberg:()=>{dispatch(getNewsBloomberg())},
};
```

here i am taking dispatch as first argument and invoking the action inside dispatch

Comment: You don't have to dispatch the actions yourself. React Redux [will do it for you if you pass an object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object). The issue with the OP's code is not calling the action creator.

Comment: thank you, i thought we can only do like this and have't red the doc's properly